# php soap envelope namespace <soap:Envelope and <SOAP-ENV:Envelope

Tags: php, soap, xml-namespaces

What is the difference between

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...>
```

and

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...>
```

and how can I switch between them?

**How can I change the response from < SOAP-ENV:Envelope to use < soap:Envelope ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference.

The XML namespace is referenced by the `xmlns` attribute as it's value (`"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`), and the shortcut to that reference is following right behind the `xmlns`, which is `soap` in your one case, and `SOAP-ENV` in the other.

That shortcut is now being used consistently as the prefix to the elements that are defined in the XML namespace. Because of the connection of the element `<Envelope>` with the defined namespace `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`, it's special meaning is known to the underlying XML parser.

The shortcut can be any allowed string - it does not matter to the XML parser as long as the correct namespace URL has been given.

I guess you have an underlying problem that makes you think that the namespace matters - you should rather explain THAT problem in your question, or probably ask a new one instead.

Comment: To put it another way: if your code relies on the prefix staying the same, fix it to rely on the URI instead, then you can ignore the difference.