# Set the value of SOAP-ENV Nusoap

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, nusoap

How to change my Soapenv:Envelope parameter from this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ejb="http://ejb.gateway.ebpp.fawryis.com/" 
xmlns:ns3678="http://tempuri.org">
```

to this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ejb="http://ejb.gateway.ebpp.fawryis.com/">
```

How to set the nusoap client Soapenv so it can be the same as the second format?

Also in every element there is xmlns empty attribute:

```
<process xmlns="http://ejb.gateway.ebpp.fawryis.com/">
<arg0 xmlns=""><Request xmlns="">
```

How to remove those xmlns attributes?

---

Here is my code:

---

```
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl_path,   TRUE);

        $client->namespaces = array(
        'SOAP-ENV'=>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        'ejb'=>"http://ejb.gateway.ebpp.fawryis.com/"
);
$parameters = array(//the parameters );
$result = $client->call("process", $parameters);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I understand you could fork Nusoap project and customize `nusoap.php` source code to return exactly what you whish. But notice that some people are telling us we don't need to bother with this prefix `SOAP-ENV`. If you do not care about which one is being serialized (SOAP-ENV or soap prefix), keep using the original nusoap project. Remember to enter the same namespace.

Here some extra information:

> You can use any string you like as a namespace prefix, just as long as
>   it maps to the appropriate namespace name. The reason why the spec
>   bothers with telling us the notational conventions is that prefix
>   names (e.g., SOAP-ENV) aren't normative.

Source: [SOAP-ENV vs. soapenv](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/200308.mbox/%3C00fd01c35ba6$ed85e620$6f01a8c0@TPX21%3E)

> ...as long as soap and SOAP-ENV refer to the same namespace URI, then
>   everything will be OK.

Source: [SOAP-ENV: vs. soap:Envelope](http://osdir.com/ml/php.nusoap.general/2006-04/msg00026.html)

> ...can be any allowed string - it does not matter to the XML parser as
>   long as the correct namespace URL has been given.

Source: [SOAP Envelope namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826463/php-soap-envelope-namespace-soapenvelope-and-soap-envenvelope)